# Flux sending duplicates due to many subscriptions

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to use a `Flux` as some sort of queue system. I want to be able to push data onto the `Flux` and subscribe to it later. Most of the time I will push 1 element and immediately subscribe after, but there are some cases where I need to wait for 2/3 elements and do some work on them before subscribing.
I've managed to make it work with a `UnicastProcessor` and a `Flux` like so:

```
private final FluxProcessor<Message> processor = UnicastProcessor.create();
private final Flux<Message> messages = processor.publish().autoconnect();

public void add(Message message){
    processor.onNext(message);
}

public void flush(){
   messages.flatMap(this::doSomeWork)
           .doOnNext(System.out::println)
           .subscribe();
}

public void flush(int buffer){
    messages.take(buffer)
            .flatMap(this::doSomeWork)
            .subscribe();
}
```

This code works but it will pile up subscriptions so it will print the same message x times for every time I subscribed. I believe this is the supposed behavior of subscribing on a `Flux` but it's not what I'm trying to achieve and I can't seem to find how to do this.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is as follows:
(every number represents a new message being pushed to the processor)

```
--------1-----(*subscribe here*)----2---3---(*subscribe here*)-----4----(*subscribe here*)
```

And the output like this:

```
1

2
3

4
```

Instead of what I'm getting:

```
1

2
3
2
3

4
4
4
```

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting such result is that you don't unsubscribe previous subscriptions so they remain active and still handle your messages.

In order to unsubscribe them you can change your `flush()` method:

```
public Disposable flush(){
    return messages
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe();
}
```

Now, you can call dispose() method which will cancel your subscription once it is not needed anymore.

```
public void run() {
    add(1);
    flush().dispose();
    System.out.println();
    add(2);
    add(3);
    flush().dispose();
    System.out.println();
    add(4);
    add(5);
    add(6);
    flush().dispose();
    System.out.println();
    add(7);
    flush().dispose();
}
```

Will result with:

```
1

2
3

4
5
6

7
```